# Identify what group KNN classified a sample in

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor

I want to be able to find which of my samples were wrongly classified by KNN, or which weren't classified at all.

I have used sckit-learn to run KNN. I have a df that has ~280000 samples split into four groups, I have 13 features by which to classify by. My precsion per group ranges from 0.30-0.90.

I expect the output to say which group each sample belongs to and which group it was classified into.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So as I'm understanding the question right you have the true group classification for your data.
In that case you can predict your whole dataset with your trained model and identify the outliers.